# IEEEtran and subfig - figures overflow onto second column

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran

```
\documentclass[final,journal,letterpaper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

some moo text
\\
\begin{figure}
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:a} \includegraphics[height=6cm]{test.png}}% < shame we need to force the linebreak
  \subfloat[]{\label{subfig:b} \includegraphics[height=6cm]{test.png}}
\end{figure}

\newpage

more moo text

\end{document}
```

I start with my MWE because I think if this is compiled and run it is easier to see the problem. Basically, the figure overflows onto the second column. I can fix this by forcing a line break - but should I have to? Can I get this to behave appropriately by some other means?

P.S to run the MWE just create a small png file called test.png with a filled colour. I wasn't sure of other means to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have scaled the height which means that the width depends on the initial image size which we don't know, however latex positions graphics just the same way ot positions letters or boxes. If there is not enough flexibility in the white space to stretch a line Tex will not leave it short, it will make the line over-full and complain.

You could use `\raggedright` or `\centering` so there is stretchability in the lines and they will break if necessary.

```
\documentclass[final,journal,letterpaper,twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

some moo text
\\
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:a} \includegraphics[height=6cm]{test.png}}}
  \mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{subfig:b} \includegraphics[height=6cm]{test.png}}}
\end{figure}

\newpage

more moo text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Height of the image doesn't particularly matter, since even a 1px png will demonstrate the problem. But FYI the image is approx 3:2 width:height. \centering did not solve the problem.

Comment: I also tried scaling the width instead of the height, but the result is the same.

Comment: demo option to what? IEEEtran? Regardless, the mbox solution has not worked for me when substituted into my MWE above.

Comment: @user1207217 put full example in answer

Comment: Demo option isn't needed. I just found that keeping the comment after the first image was causing it to not overflow. mbox works. Accepted. Thank you very much

Comment: @user1207217 demo option is only needed if you haven't got the image it just replaces all images by a black rectangle, it makes examples portable (if dull:-)

Comment: Aaaaah .. yes I see .. I will edit my question and bear that in mind for future :)